# How to read xml column from db2 using jdbc

Tags: xml, jdbc, db2

Let us say I have a table called ABC with 2 columns id(number), content(xml) in DB2.

```
String q="select * from ABC where id=121";
Connection conn = getConnection(dbUrl,schemaName,userName,password);
Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(q);
while(rs.next())
{
   //HERE HOW CAN I GET CONTENT COLUMN VALUE IN STRING FORMAT
}
```

I have tried rs.getObject(i), rs.getString(i) and rs.getSQLXML(i).getString() but no luck... And I need only db2 solution

I have fixed my self:

```
String q="select * from ABC where id=121";
Connection conn = getConnection(dbUrl,schemaName,userName,password);
Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(q);
ResultSetMetaData rsmd = rs.getMetaData();
while(rs.next())
{
   if(rsmd.getColumnTypeName(i).equalsIgnoreCase("XML"))
   {
            convertInStreamToString(rs.getBinaryStream(i));

    }
    else
    {
        rs.getObject(i);
    }
}

private String convertInStreamToString(InputStream data) throws Exception
{
        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
        int n = 0;
        while ((n=data.read(buf))>=0)
        {
           baos.write(buf, 0, n);
        }

        data.close();
        byte[] bytes = baos.toByteArray();
        return new String(bytes); 
}
```

Hope this helps...

Answer (score 1):

XML rows are implemented as large objects. Try `rs.getClob(i)`, then call `getSubstring` to retrieve the xml from it. [Here's an example.](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v9/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.db2.udb.apdv.java.doc/doc/cjvjdlob.htm)